# Intent в методе onReceive в BroadcastReceiver-е не содержит StringExtra

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

Я создаю уведомление со следующим `Intent`-ом:

```
Intent buttonIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ButtonReceiver.class);
buttonIntent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION);
buttonIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_ERROR_ID);
buttonIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS, details);
PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);
Notification.Builder builder = getNotificationBuilder(errorMsg)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(errorMsg))
                .setAutoCancel(true);
if (isDetailed) {
  builder.addAction(R.drawable.baseline_info_white_18dp,
                    getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.more_info),
                    btPendingIntent);
}
return builder.addAction(R.drawable.baseline_close_white_18dp,
                         getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.close),
                         btPendingIntent)
              .build();
```

И ловлю этот `Intent` в методе `onReceive` в `BroadcastReceiver`-е:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        String details = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIFICATION_DETAILS);
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        if (details != null) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Details: " + details);
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Details is null");
        }
        ...
}
```

И в дебагере я вижу, что `buttonIntent` изначально имеет два вложения (extra): поле `buttonIntent.mExtras.mMap` имеет размер, равный 2, и содержит значения `value[0]` - строка `details` - и `value[1]` - число типа `int`, `NOTIFICATION_ERROR_ID`. Однако `Intent` в методе `onReceive` `BroadcastReceiver`-a содержит поле `buttonIntent.mExtras.mMap`, которое имеет размер 1, и содержит единственное значение - `value[0]`, равное `NOTIFICATION_ERROR_ID`. Соответственно, строка `details` в методе `onReceive` всё время имеет значение `null`. Почему так происходит?

**UPD**

Я нашла решение - вместо

```
PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, 0);
```

использовать

```
PendingIntent btPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, buttonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Тогда `Intent` в методе `onReceive` в `BroadcastReceiver`-а получает `StringExtra`. Осталось только понять, как именно `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` влияет на это, какая его роль тут...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть в том, что система не создаёт `PendingIntent` каждый раз новый, а сначала ищет существующий, с таким же `Intent` без учёта экстра. А дальше действует, согласно флагу. `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` обновляет экстра, `0` ничего не делает - оставляет существующие данные.
В этом уроке подробно разбирается как работают флаги: [startandroid.ru: Урок 119. PendingIntent – флаги, requestCode. AlarmManager](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html)